# Post search in Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My Requirement is like , I want to search all the post posted by different people with keyword which i want.
I had tried with graph API Explore but I am unable to open link https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post.

Please can you let me know How would I get my issue solved ? or please suggest any solution that so that it meet my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, Public Post search is no longer available: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Another possibility would be the Public Feed API, but you can´t apply to that one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

In other words: It´s not possible.